# 19:259 Error: `'` can be escaped with `&apos;`, `&lsquo;`, `&#39;`, `&rsquo;`. react/no-unescaped-entities

Tags: next.js, eslint, vercel

I am trying to deploy my project to the cloud using vercel but halfway through it show me an error message: 19:259  Error: `'` can be escaped with `&apos;`, `&lsquo;`, `&#39;`, `&rsquo;`.  react/no-unescaped-entities.

About.jsx code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image';
import AboutImg from '../public/assets/about.png';


const About = () => {
  return (
    <div id='about' className='w-full md:h-screen p-2 flex items-center py-16'>
      <div className='max-w-[1240px] m-auto md:grid grid-cols-3 gap-8'>
        <div className='col-span-2'>
          <p className='uppercase text-xl tracking-widest text-[#5651e5]'>
            About Me
          </p>
          <h2 className='py-4'>Who I Am?</h2>
          <p className='py-2 text-gray-600'>
            / / I am not your average developer
          </p>
          <p className='py-2 text-gray-600'>
            test
          </p>

          
          
          <a href='/../public/assets/about.png'>
            <p className='py-2 text-gray-600 underline cursor-pointer'>
              Download file
            </p>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div className='w-full h-auto m-auto shadow-xl shadow-gray-400 rounded-xl flex items-center justify-center p-4 hover:scale-105 ease-in duration-300'>
          <Image src={AboutImg} className='rounded-xl' alt='/' />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default About;
```

skills.jsx:

```
import Image from 'next/image';
import React from 'react';
import { AiFillHtml5 } from "react-icons/Ai";
import { DiCss3 } from "react-icons/Di";
import { DiPython } from "react-icons/Di";
import { AiFillGithub } from "react-icons/Ai";
import { TbBrandNextjs } from "react-icons/Tb";
import { DiDjango } from "react-icons/Di";
import { SiTailwindcss } from "react-icons/Si";
import { FaDocker } from "react-icons/Fa";

const Skills = () => {
  return (
    <div id='skills' className='w-full lg:h-screen p-2'>
      <div className='max-w-[1240px] mx-auto flex flex-col justify-center h-full'>
        <p className='text-xl tracking-widest uppercase text-[#5651e5]'>
          My Skills
        </p>
        <h2 className='py-4'>What I Can Do?</h2>
        
        <div className='grid grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-8'>
        <div className='p-6 shadow-xl rounded-xl hover:scale-10 ease-in duration-300'>
            <div className='grid grid-cols-2 justify-center items-center'>
            <AiFillHtml5 className="w-10 h-10 bg-blue-400 text-gray-100 m-3 p-1 shadow-xl rounded-md" />
              <div>
                <h3>HTML</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div className='p-6 shadow-xl rounded-xl hover:scale-10 ease-in duration-300'>
            <div className='grid grid-cols-2 justify-center items-center'>
            <DiCss3 className="w-10 h-10 bg-blue-400 text-gray-100 m-3 p-1 shadow-xl rounded-md" />
              <div>
                <h3>CSS</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div className='p-6 shadow-xl rounded-xl hover:scale-10 ease-in duration-300'>
            <div className='grid grid-cols-2 justify-center items-center'>
            <DiPython className="w-10 h-10 bg-blue-400 text-gray-100 m-3 p-1 shadow-xl rounded-md" />
              <div>
                <h3>Python</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div className='p-6 shadow-xl rounded-xl hover:scale-10 ease-in duration-300'>
            <div className='grid grid-cols-2 justify-center items-center'>
            <DiDjango className="w-10 h-10 bg-blue-400 text-gray-100 m-3 p-1 shadow-xl rounded-md" />
              <div>
                <h3>Django</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          
          
          <div className='p-6 shadow-xl rounded-xl hover:scale-10 ease-in duration-300'>
            <div className='grid grid-cols-2 justify-center items-center'>
            <SiTailwindcss className="w-10 h-10 bg-blue-400 text-gray-100 m-3 p-1 shadow-xl rounded-md" />
              <div>
                <h3>Tailwind CSS</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div className='p-6 shadow-xl rounded-xl hover:scale-10 ease-in duration-300'>
            <div className='grid grid-cols-2 justify-center items-center'>
            <FaDocker className="w-10 h-10 bg-blue-400 text-gray-100 m-3 p-1 shadow-xl rounded-md" />
              <div>
                <h3>Docker</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div className='p-6 shadow-xl rounded-xl hover:scale-10 ease-in duration-300'>
            <div className='grid grid-cols-2 justify-center items-center'>
            <AiFillGithub className="w-10 h-10 bg-blue-400 text-gray-100 m-3 p-1 shadow-xl rounded-md" />
              <div>
                <h3>Github</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div className='p-6 shadow-xl rounded-xl hover:scale-10 ease-in duration-300'>
            <div className='grid grid-cols-2 justify-center items-center'>
            <TbBrandNextjs className="w-10 h-10 bg-blue-400 text-gray-100 m-3 p-1 shadow-xl rounded-md" />
              <div>
                <h3>NextJs</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Skills;
```

What does this error mean and how do I solve this? I have no issue when I am running on localhost, just deployment have this error issue.

Comment: Means you have an unescaped or misplaced apostrophe. However the code you've posted doesn't seem to have that issue.

Comment: hmm, it same goes for my other part of the code too

Comment: is there a way to disable that in my code?

Comment: Yes, you can go to the eslintrc.json file. @Shadowwalker


Then, you apply what rules you want to turn off like:

`{
    "rules": {
        "react/no-unescaped-entities": "off",
    }
}
`

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error and it was pointing to my code where I add a simple text like this

```
<p>dont't have a account?</p>
```

I managed to fix it by taking the text inside template literals

```
 <p>{`dont't have a account?`}</p>
```

You can also do something like this

```
 <p>{`dont&apos;t have a account?`}</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

This error is due to the nextjs rules.

To disable this, go to .eslintrc.json file and add rule in it just below the extends key

ie. your .eslintrc.json will look like below

```
{
  "extends": "next/core-web-vitals",
  "rules": {
    "react/no-unescaped-entities": "off"
  }
}
```

try building again

for more info go to https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/eslint#disabling-rules

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem Instead of

```
<p>Enter leader's name</p>
```

try

```
<p>{`Enter leader's name`}</p>
```